# ASP.NET Printing using Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, printing

Original question:

How can I allow my users to select a printer tray when printing a Reporting Services report from my ASP.NET application?

Follow up:

Just to follow up, my question was rubbish. I should have phrased it as..

Is it possible, using reporting services, when printing the report to say "page X" goes to tray 1, "Page Y" goes to tray 2?

We have a customer who would like each covering page to be on headed paper, but subsequent pages on plain.

Comment: Do you use the report viewer control or the reporting services webservice?

Answer (score 0):

If you render the report using the reporting services webservice you can print the report using the normal C# printer routine. Use the [PrinterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.papersources(VS.71).aspx) class to set the correct PaperSource

**Answer to follow up:**
Using the webservice you may render each page separately. Ie. create an array of rendered report pages. This way you may print one page to one tray and the rest to another tray.

This [sample code](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_24547424.html) should help you.